# Java For Loop Practice

Tags: java, for-loop

Was doing some Java practices and I got stuck at this particular question, I am given the following code:

```
public class DistanceSeparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printSeparatorSequence(3);
        printSeparatorSequence(5);
        printSeparatorSequence(8);
    }

    public static void printSeparatorSequence(int numberOfElements) {
        for () {

        }
        System.out.println();
    } //end of method printSeparatorSequence

} // end of class
```

And I am supposed to modify the code using **A SINGLE FOR LOOP** to show that:

If numberOfElements = 5

```
1 3 7 13 21
```

If numberOfElements = 7

```
1 3 7 13 21 31 43
```

Each showing an increment of + 2, +4, +6, +8, +10 and +12
The final output is to be this:

```
1 3 7
1 3 7 13 21
1 3 7 13 21 31 43 57
```

I just can't seem to get my head around how to get that outcome, and this is after 2hours of trying (yes I am that bad). Any help, please?

*edit* This was what I had, before deciding to seek help, it's obviously not working.

```
 int j = 0;
 for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++) {          
     j = i * 2; // + by how much
     int z = i + j; //sum            
     System.out.print(z + "");
 }
```

*edit 2* now I get it, oh my, to think I was so close. Guess I was too cluttered after being stuck for some time. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sounds like you need to re-read the chapter. Hint: You have 2 variables, one for the loop counting from `1` to `numberOfElements` and another for the value to print.

Comment: The loop counting from 1 to the numberOfElements I get, it's the getting of the values to print that is giving me the problems. Can't seem to get the logic right to have the value added by 2 then 4 then 6 then 8 subsequently.

Comment: In that snippet, you don't need `j`. `i + j` is the same as `i * 3`. Also, you can `System.out.print` with an `int`. Even if you couldn't, `+ ""` is extremely bad practice and you should use `Integer.toString(z)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to accomplish result you expected.

```
int current = 1;    

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {

   current += i*2;
   System.out.print(current + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are regenerating `int z` everytime the loop is called,
All you have to do is define z outside the loop and instantiate `z` as `1` and also, you are not retaining the previous values of `z` so that's why it wasn't working. So it should be `z = z + j` and put this line below the `print` statement and you are done.

Here is an snippet of code which would help you **my way**:

```
int j = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=numberOfElements; i++) {
    System.out.println(j);
    j = j + 2*i;
}
```

And, here is an snippet of code which would help you **your way**:

```
int j = 0;
int z = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++)
    {          
    j = i * 2; // + by how much
    System.out.print(z + " ");
    z = z + j; //sum            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to keep another variable to keep track of the difference (the change), and then constantly update it by the power of 2 of the iteration, i.e. for the first loop only increase it by 2^1, then by 2^2, then 2^3 and so on).

An example of how to achieve that:

```
for (int i = 0, diff = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++, diff += 2*i) {
    System.out.print((1 + diff) + " ");
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: After you've edited your question with your code segment, you can see your problem was with this line:

```
int z = i + j; //sum
```

Since both `i` and `j` advance with each iteration, you lose your offset (you constantly reset it). You need to keep it static (like in my example: 1), and only update `j` by `2*i` each iteration, otherwise your "base" for calculation is constantly changing and the formula doesn't hold anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Note the trend.

You are adding a multiple of 2 to the previous number to get the next number. The multiple of 2 to be added depends upon the position of the number. For example, to get the 1st number, you add `2 x 0` to `1`. To get the 2nd number, you add `2 x 1` to the previous number (that gives 3). To get the 3rd number, you add `2 x 2` to the previous number (that gives 7). To get the 4th number, you add `2 x 3` to the previous number (that gives 13).

To get the number at nth position, you add `2 x (n-1)` to the previous number.

Now take a look at the example below, keeping the above explanation in mind.

```
public static void printSeparatorSequence(int numberOfElements)  {
int number = 1;
for (int i = 0; i<numberOfElements;i++) {
  number = number + 2 * i;
  System.out.print(number);
}

System.out.println();

} //end of method printSeparatorSequence
} // end of class
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution of your problem. I have discussed the code by the comment lines given within the code.

```
public class DistanceSeparator 
{
    /* Main Method */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /* printSeparatorSequence Function is Called */
        printSeparatorSequence(3);
        printSeparatorSequence(5);
        printSeparatorSequence(8);
    }

    /* printSeparatorSequence Function Definition */
    public static void printSeparatorSequence(int NumberOfElements)
    {
        /* variable j is used to get the multiples of 
         2 by multiplying with variable i within the for loop 
         and variable sum is used to get the total value */
        int j=2,sum=1;
        for(int i=0;i<NumberOfElements;i++)
        {
            sum=sum+(j*i);
            /* Here total sum is printed with a space */
            System.out.print(sum+" ");
        }
        /* It is used for new line */
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```